# Jersey rest framework - authorization - some doubts

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey

I read about jersey framework for rest service on this page  http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-restful-client-api-authentication-example/|

And I don't understand one thing. 
For instance, when we have

```
  @Path("/users")
  public class JerseyService 
  {
  @RolesAllowed("USER")
  public String doLogin(@QueryParam("username") String uname,
  @QueryParam("password") String result)
```

It means that user with role user can modify (by this method) ALL the users? Not only himself in the database? I am writing android app and I can imagine situation where someone is using for instance Advanced REST client. He logs on the service and modifying queries in appropriate way and strongly mess my database. For instance write some points to other user or something similar. How can I shut out this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey (and similar Spring Security) operate on Resource Types and Roles.

So, if you permit Role "USER" to operate on resource "Users", you can't block specific user from editing other users with Jersey only.

What you can do is use SecurityContext to get current user, and block dangerous operations if his credentials are different from user being changed.

Here's a good example on SecurityContext:
https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/jersey-jax-rs-securitycontext-in-action/

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems to be pretty good. Is it proper to use it with native mobile application on Android platrform? ;) I read about oauth2 and think about use one of these solutions.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're writing Android client that will communicate with Jersey server, right?

Comment: Right. I plan the application, choose appriopriate technologies. This is my first bigger app. So, to sum up - I make preparation and not all is determined. Initially I thought about spring, not jersey.

Comment: Both Spring and Jersey are totally fine for that, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, so in case of spring - for security classic spring security? Or something other?

Comment: Spring Security should do the job.

Comment: Ok, thanks you ;) I think that now I can research on my own ;)